# <div> Shrinking On Click (using jQueryUI bounce effect)

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

UPDATE: This has been fixed as of 1.9 of jQueryUI (http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7725).

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/FeaMg/10/

I can't figure out why the button shrinks whenever I click on it.

I need it to use a percentage for width, it works just fine when I set the width to a pixel amount.

Any ideas what I can do to stop this from happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works :)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //When button is clicked
    $('.menuButton').click(function()
    {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
        //Make the button bounce
        $(this).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300);
    });
});
```

Fork: http://jsfiddle.net/ynAHy/

---

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //When button is clicked
    $('.menuButton').click(function()
    {
        $(this).css('width', $(this).width());
        //Make the button bounce
        $(this).effect('bounce', { times:3 }, 300, function(){
            $(this).css('width', '50%');
        });
    });
});
```

Using the callback of the effect function as mentioned here: http://ui-dev.jquery.com/demos/effect/
UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/dRRhE/

Comment: It loses its percentage-based width though =(. If I add "$(this).css('width', '25%');" to the end of the click function, it starts acting like it did with my first example as well, so unfortunately not fixed yet =(.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your answer, I'm fairly new to programming, and as soon as I saw there was a callback for that function, I literally jumped up from my chair, and laughed with my friend about it over Skype (who's working on a voice recognition project). Thanks again! Karma++